# Connect two containers through docker network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

My objective is connect two different containers to get data, in other words:

- I have an instance of OpenCTI working in my docker , and I can access it through my browser (http://localhost:8080).
- Consequently, I am developing another one to get data from OpenCTI.

To connect both, I already created a docker network called "minharede".

**However is not working**.

The configuration of my containers is:

**Docker-compose file of OpenCTI:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2.6
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/data
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.1
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.ml.enabled=false
    restart: always
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
  minio:
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2022-02-26T02-54-46Z
    volumes:
      - s3data:/data
    ports:
      - "9800:9800"
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: ${MINIO_ROOT_USER}
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD}    
    command: server /data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3
    restart: always
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.9-management
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
    volumes:
      - amqpdata:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    restart: always
  opencti:
    image: opencti/platform:5.2.1          
    environment:
      - NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8096
      - APP__PORT=8080
      - APP__ADMIN__EMAIL=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_EMAIL}
      - APP__ADMIN__PASSWORD=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      - APP__ADMIN__TOKEN=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_TOKEN}
      - APP__APP_LOGS__LOGS_LEVEL=error
      - REDIS__HOSTNAME=redis
      - REDIS__PORT=6379
      - ELASTICSEARCH__URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - MINIO__ENDPOINT=minio
      - MINIO__PORT=9000
      - MINIO__USE_SSL=false
      - MINIO__ACCESS_KEY=${MINIO_ROOT_USER}
      - MINIO__SECRET_KEY=${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - RABBITMQ__HOSTNAME=rabbitmq
      - RABBITMQ__PORT=5672
      - RABBITMQ__PORT_MANAGEMENT=15672
      - RABBITMQ__MANAGEMENT_SSL=false
      - RABBITMQ__USERNAME=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      - RABBITMQ__PASSWORD=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
      - SMTP__HOSTNAME=${SMTP_HOSTNAME}
      - SMTP__PORT=25
      - PROVIDERS__LOCAL__STRATEGY=LocalStrategy
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - elasticsearch
      - minio
      - rabbitmq
    restart: always
  worker:
    image: opencti/worker:5.2.1
    environment:
      - OPENCTI_URL=http://opencti:8080
      - OPENCTI_TOKEN=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_TOKEN}
      - WORKER_LOG_LEVEL=info
    depends_on:
      - opencti
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3
    restart: always
  connector-history:
    image: opencti/connector-history:5.2.1
    environment:
      - OPENCTI_URL=http://opencti:8080
      - OPENCTI_TOKEN=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_TOKEN}
      - CONNECTOR_ID=${CONNECTOR_HISTORY_ID} # Valid UUIDv4
      - CONNECTOR_TYPE=STREAM
      - CONNECTOR_NAME=History
      - CONNECTOR_SCOPE=history
      - CONNECTOR_CONFIDENCE_LEVEL=15 # From 0 (Unknown) to 100 (Fully trusted)
      - CONNECTOR_LOG_LEVEL=info
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - opencti
  connector-export-file-stix:
    image: opencti/connector-export-file-stix:5.2.1
    environment:
      - OPENCTI_URL=http://opencti:8080
      - OPENCTI_TOKEN=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_TOKEN}
      - CONNECTOR_ID=${CONNECTOR_EXPORT_FILE_STIX_ID} # Valid UUIDv4
      - CONNECTOR_TYPE=INTERNAL_EXPORT_FILE
      - CONNECTOR_NAME=ExportFileStix2
      - CONNECTOR_SCOPE=application/json
      - CONNECTOR_CONFIDENCE_LEVEL=15 # From 0 (Unknown) to 100 (Fully trusted)
      - CONNECTOR_LOG_LEVEL=info
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - opencti
  connector-export-file-csv:
    image: opencti/connector-export-file-csv:5.2.1
    environment:
      - OPENCTI_URL=http://opencti:8080
      - OPENCTI_TOKEN=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_TOKEN}
      - CONNECTOR_ID=${CONNECTOR_EXPORT_FILE_CSV_ID} # Valid UUIDv4
      - CONNECTOR_TYPE=INTERNAL_EXPORT_FILE
      - CONNECTOR_NAME=ExportFileCsv
      - CONNECTOR_SCOPE=text/csv
      - CONNECTOR_CONFIDENCE_LEVEL=15 # From 0 (Unknown) to 100 (Fully trusted)
      - CONNECTOR_LOG_LEVEL=info
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - opencti
  connector-export-file-txt:
    image: opencti/connector-export-file-txt:5.2.1
    environment:
      - OPENCTI_URL=http://opencti:8080
      - OPENCTI_TOKEN=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_TOKEN}
      - CONNECTOR_ID=${CONNECTOR_EXPORT_FILE_TXT_ID} # Valid UUIDv4
      - CONNECTOR_TYPE=INTERNAL_EXPORT_FILE
      - CONNECTOR_NAME=ExportFileTxt
      - CONNECTOR_SCOPE=text/plain
      - CONNECTOR_CONFIDENCE_LEVEL=15 # From 0 (Unknown) to 100 (Fully trusted)
      - CONNECTOR_LOG_LEVEL=info
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - opencti
  connector-import-file-stix:
    image: opencti/connector-import-file-stix:5.2.1
    environment:
      - OPENCTI_URL=http://opencti:8080
      - OPENCTI_TOKEN=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_TOKEN}
      - CONNECTOR_ID=${CONNECTOR_IMPORT_FILE_STIX_ID} # Valid UUIDv4
      - CONNECTOR_TYPE=INTERNAL_IMPORT_FILE
      - CONNECTOR_NAME=ImportFileStix
      - CONNECTOR_VALIDATE_BEFORE_IMPORT=true # Validate any bundle before import
      - CONNECTOR_SCOPE=application/json,text/xml
      - CONNECTOR_AUTO=true # Enable/disable auto-import of file
      - CONNECTOR_CONFIDENCE_LEVEL=15 # From 0 (Unknown) to 100 (Fully trusted)
      - CONNECTOR_LOG_LEVEL=info
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - opencti
  connector-import-document:
    image: opencti/connector-import-document:5.2.1
    environment:
      - OPENCTI_URL=http://opencti:8080
      - OPENCTI_TOKEN=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_TOKEN}
      - CONNECTOR_ID=${CONNECTOR_IMPORT_DOCUMENT_ID} # Valid UUIDv4
      - CONNECTOR_TYPE=INTERNAL_IMPORT_FILE
      - CONNECTOR_NAME=ImportDocument
      - CONNECTOR_VALIDATE_BEFORE_IMPORT=true # Validate any bundle before import
      - CONNECTOR_SCOPE=application/pdf,text/plain,text/html
      - CONNECTOR_AUTO=true # Enable/disable auto-import of file
      - CONNECTOR_ONLY_CONTEXTUAL=false # Only extract data related to an entity (a report, a threat actor, etc.)
      - CONNECTOR_CONFIDENCE_LEVEL=15 # From 0 (Unknown) to 100 (Fully trusted)
      - CONNECTOR_LOG_LEVEL=info
      - IMPORT_DOCUMENT_CREATE_INDICATOR=true
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - opencti

networks: 
  default: 
    external: 
      name: minharede #network created for the purpose

volumes:
  esdata:
  s3data:
  redisdata:
  amqpdata:
```

**Docker-Compose file Container B**:

```
    version: '3.4'
    
    services:
      teste:
        image: teste
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    networks: 
      default: 
        external: 
          name: minharede  #docker network created for the purpose
```

The config.yml of container B is:

```
opencti:
  url: "http://localhost:8080"
  token: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" #is hidden to post here

connector:
  id: "245b2de5-b85e-4236-bedd-97540b133ea2"
  type: "INTERNAL_ENRICHMENT"
  name: "osthreatenrichment"
  scope: "IPv4-Addr, IPv6-Addr, Domain-Name"
  auto: true
  confidence_level: 70 #From 0 (unknown) to 100 (Fully trusted)
  log_level: "info"
```

When I try to run my container B on Visual Code to test it (it's connected to the docker), I get this error:

> Exception has occurred: ValueError OpenCTI API is not reachable.
> Waiting for OpenCTI API to start or check your configuration...

Anyone can helpe me?? Thank you guys!

(image attached)
[image: API is not reachable]

Comment: Please show the contents of your config.yml. In docker-compose you access other containers on the network by their service name (not localhost)

Comment: What's the host name you're trying to use to connect to the other container?  It will be simpler if you can run both containers in the same Compose file, is there a reason to have them separated?

Comment: @atultw i added the confi.yml configuration in the description of the problem. Can you see it? So, I must replace the url?

Comment: @DavidMaze I am not running the container in the same Compose file, because container OpenCTI is already implemented in the docker, and I am developing the container B in Visual Code that is connected to the Docker to test my code. The idea is integrate the final solution in the compose, but not right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, during debug in VSCode that is connected to the Docker, the container in development (Cntainer B) connects a default network, in my case was a network called "bridge" . Consequently, I wasn't getting a connection to the same network that container OpenCTI and to solve this I performed the reverse, I connected the container OpenCTI to the network "bridge" where my container in development is connected.
After that, I went to check the IP address of the service in my container OpenCTI that I wanted get a connection from container B, and I changed the url from `http://opencti:8080` to `http://172.xx.x.x:8080`(you only have to replace xx by the correct numbers of the IP address) and **worked fine for me**!!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `http://localhost:8080` as the target, which cannot work, as each container is its own `localhost`.

```yaml
opencti:
  url: "http://localhost:8080" # this should be the other services name
```

Change it to the target container's network alias (compose service name). In this case `opencti`.

---

When I replicate your setup, I get a deprecation warning

```
WARN[0000] network default: network.external.name is deprecated in favor of network.name
```

I have fixed this warning, and could successfully create the setup.

First, I create the network:

```
docker network create minharede
```

Then, I create a dummy service in a.yaml and run `docker compose -p a -f a.yaml up -d`:

```yaml
# a.yaml
services:
  my-svc:
    image: traefik/whoami
networks:
  default:
    name: minharede
    external: true
```

Finally, I create another service in a different file to curl for the network alias `whoami` of the service.

```yaml
# b.yaml
services:
  curl:
    image: curlimages/curl
    command: -s my-svc
networks:
  default:
    name: minharede
    external: true
```

When, I run `docker compose -p b -f b.yaml up` I can see the following output.

```
Attaching to curl_1
curl_1  | Hostname: d63e37dd5363
curl_1  | IP: 127.0.0.1
curl_1  | IP: 172.22.0.2
curl_1  | RemoteAddr: 172.22.0.3:38960
curl_1  | GET / HTTP/1.1
curl_1  | Host: my-svc
curl_1  | User-Agent: curl/7.82.0-DEV
curl_1  | Accept: */*
curl_1  | 
curl_1 exited with code 0
```

So what you are trying to do is certainly possible. You are just using the wrong hostname. In my example, you can see the service name in the compose file of the service I am trying to curl is `my-svc`. That's also what I am using for the hostname in the curl command.

---

You could actually simplify this by not using an external network for `a` but still reference `a's` default network as external in `b`.

```yaml
# a.yaml
networks:
  default:
    name: minharede
```

```yaml
# b.yaml
networks:
  default:
    name: minharede
    external: true
```

Then you only need to make sure you start `a` before `b`.

Comment: I am trying to reach to the image "plataforma" of the containter openCTI. You can see the image in the url : ![image.png](postimg.cc/CzVB5vVK) . I changed the link according with the hostname to `http://plataforma:8080` and still not working, API is not reachable.

Comment: @MdaCosta, can you show the service in the compose file? You have ... there. At least show the service name. Otherwise its hard to validate what you are doing. The way you word it, it sounds like you are trying to use the image name and not the service name. In my example those are the same, It may be confusing. I have changed that, now and named the service `my-svc`.

Comment: I mean, please update your question and show the service name, for openCTI.

Comment: I already updated the question with the Docker compose file of the container OpenCTI. Can you check it please?

Comment: @MdaCosta, use `opencti` as hostname.

Comment: Got the same error, API is not reachable :(

Comment: @MdaCosta, are you using also the right port?

Comment: I changed the url **from** `http://localhost:8080` **to** `http://opencti:8080` . It is right ?

Comment: @MdaCosta, yes this is right. You can also see it on the worker service for example. Its using the same url. Unless maybe openctpi listens on more than one port. Maybe the api is not the port of the worker. You can exec into your container and try curl or nslookup or similar to see if you can at least resolve the dns.

Comment: This guy solved as described here https://github.com/OpenCTI-Platform/opencti/issues/1061, however supposedly I am doing the same.

Comment: @MdaCosta have you already tried to use the new syntax for the external network, as shown in my answer? In your post you are still using the depricated form.

Comment: You mean like this: [![image.png](https://i.postimg.cc/V6jHPQbc/image.png)](https://postimg.cc/BLnC2zgh)

Comment: @MdaCosta, yes like that.

Comment: Yes,I tried it. Look at this : ![image.png](postimg.cc/0zcFMjLm) . The container that I am testing, from Visual Code, supposedly is running as you can see in the image. However, when i perform docker inspect minharede I only have images of OpenCTI container as you can see here: ![image.png](postimg.cc/Vd6m7ymj) . How it's possible? After explore the networks, I found that the container B is connected to the network "bridge" as you can see in this image [![image.png](https://i.postimg.cc/zXkTt3Wq/image.png)](https://postimg.cc/SJJXjSDP) . I don't know how,I configured to the network "minharede"

Answer (score 0):

The [compose reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#networks) has this example:

```
services:
  some-service:
    networks:
     - some-network
     - other-network
```

And it states:

> Networks to join, referencing entries under the top-level networks key.

You need to specify the network definition at the top level of your compose file, and in your service definition you need to specify the named network.

However that's not the whole story. As @davidmaze suggests, it will be easier to accomplish this within one compose file rather than multiple. Docker compose treats each compose as a separate "app" and everything within a compose is "namespaced" to that app.

---

In order to get what you want you'll need to host your named network outside of the compose file. The `docker network` command is the direction you'd have to go in, but I think a whole tutorial on how to achieve this is outside the scope of an SO answer.

In order to maintain a solution to this, every developer workstation would have to hold and maintain an identically configured named network which both compose-apps could join. This is counterproductive -- the point of developing within a docker compose is to hold the entire development environment within the repository itself.

In any case, the key component is building a named network on your workstation with `docker network create <name>` and then attaching to it within your compose file via the `external` attribute.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network (scroll up just a tad, the documentation site for docker misaligns by about 150px when an #anchor is loaded):

> If you want your containers to join a pre-existing network, use the external option:

```
services:
  # ...
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my-pre-existing-network
```

Comment: Its not really true. Each service in the compose file will be joined to the default network. So you dont need to list it explicitly under the networks key of a given service.

Comment: @TheFool By default, yes, every service is going to be joined to the default network. The question is, how to get them to join an alternate network. The answer is: the network must be specified at both the top level and the service level.